# What does '\ ' mean in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, string, intellij-idea

I got some JavaScript code that contains HTML code inside strings. Some strings start with `'\ '` (backslash, space). What does this sequence do?

This is weird because the strings aren't highlighted as HTML code after the `'\ '` in IntelliJ IDEA v14.1.4. Here's a screenshot of some sample-code.

[image: HTML-highlighting in IntelliJ]

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those backslashes only escapes the space character that follows.

`"\ "` is the same thing as `" "`.

In a JavaScript string you can escape any character, even those which doesn't need escaping. Spaces doesn't need escaping, so the backslashes doesn't serve any purpose in this case.

Answer (score 3):

It does very little. An escaped space is a space in JavaScript string literals.

```js
alert("\ " === ' ');
```

Possibly the author just wanted to highlight the fact that there was a space at the front of the string.

Answer (score 1):

A backslash is an escape character in JavaScript. Escape characters change the way in which the coding language will process the characters which immediately follow them. In this case, `\ <div>` (backslash followed by a space, then ) is the same as `<div>` (space, followed by ). In some cases, such as `\t`, the slash would transform the following character into something else - a tab character in this case. Since a space following a backslash doesn't mean anything "special" to JavaScript, the "escaped space" just gets interpreted as a space when this code runs in the browser.

Now, the reason for the highlighting difference is that your IDE is interpreting and displaying the code that follows them according to it's own understanding of how to colorize your code. For whatever reason, it does not recognize the "green highlighted" HTML as HTML. I agree the coloring scheme your IDE is using after the escape character is a bit confusing, since all of the strings (vars) shown in your example are perfectly legitimate strings. I would (personally) want an IDE to display them consistently.

Learn more about JavaScript escape character usage here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character#JavaScript

Answer (score -1):

They are escape characters. It allows the parser to read them without running them as code basically.

Answer (score -1):

The '\' is an escape character for the space that follows. The \ here is used but is not needed, so that the space is recognised as a space and not an error in the IDE (it wouldn't be as it's quoted around "", but the author has included it to indicate it should be there).

Looking at the structure of the code, it's probably to include a space between every Hallo Welt if it was displayed on the wep page.

P.s, this shouldn't compile as you can't declare variable v3 twice, which you have.